# Which Algorithm or combination of Algorithms to use to develop supervised Video Event detection?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

I have to develop a video event detection tool in ticketing counter.The tool must take photographs of persons who jumb over gate without taking tickets.I have a set of videos in which people jumbing over gate.So with that data in hand How can i implement a Video event detection tool?I am new to video analytics.I don't know where to start.Where can i find some good tutorial about supervised video event detection.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using a 3D convoluted neural network. Traditional 2D convoluted neural networks excel at identifying objects in images, and 3D convolution is used for identifying objects or movements also across multiple frames (i.e., time). [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn.html#conv3d) offers this capability.

Comment: Thank you,Do you have any github projects related to video event detection?I am currently using python.Is that ok for Video analytics?

Comment: @Ceem I'm sure there are others, but here is my own: https://github.com/RyanZotti/Self-Driving-Car. I use 3D convoluted neural networks to detect when to turn the car: https://github.com/RyanZotti/Self-Driving-Car/blob/master/train_3d_conv_net.py. Python is a great choice. My entire stack is in python